# Android canvas geopoint line drawing

Tags: android, gps, drawing, line, android-canvas

I am developing an android app which allows users to trace their route and displays it to them. I have a mapview which uses gps, finds a users location, saves each location to an arraylist and draws lines to each point on an overlay all working fine on the actual google maps. however, I want to create a more detailed view using androids canvas feature. The canvas displays (as a green background) but the lines (and points) dont show up when I try to draw between an array list of geopoints. I set the content view to be a canvas by calling an inner class as follows:

```
setContentView(new SimulationDraw(this));

this.setRequestedOrientation(
ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
paint = new Paint(Color.LTGRAY);
```

And this is the class in question:

```
class SimulationDraw extends View {
    private ColourGeoPoint firstPoint;
    private Object lastCGP;
    private int lastCGPLong;
    private int lastCGPLat;


    public SimulationDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        firstPoint = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);

        paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 

        for(ColourGeoPoint point : trackOverlay.geoPointsArray){
            int loclat = point.getGeoLocation().getLatitudeE6();
            System.out.println("LOCLAT" + loclat);
            int loclong = point.getGeoLocation().getLongitudeE6();
            System.out.println("LOCLONG" + loclong);

            canvas.drawPoint(loclat, loclong, paint);
            if (lastCGP == null) {
                lastCGP = point;
                lastCGPLat = point.getGeoLocation().getLatitudeE6();
                System.out.println("LASTCGPLAT" + lastCGPLat);
                lastCGPLong = point.getGeoLocation().getLongitudeE6();
                System.out.println("LASTCGPLONG" + lastCGPLong);
            } else {
                Path path = new Path();
                path.moveTo(loclat,loclong);
                path.lineTo(lastCGPLat, lastCGPLong);
                canvas.drawLine(loclat, loclong, lastCGPLat, lastCGPLong, paint);
                canvas.drawPoint(loclat, loclong, paint);
                lastCGP = point;
            }
        }
```

So my question is, where am I going wrong? Ive inserted a few print statements and tried to draw the canvas and the point but nothing shows up besides the green background. I get no runtime errors.

As a side note, the print statements show up the Geopoints as expected. Do I need to convert the geopoints to screen points somehow? Also im drawing this over the top over a mapview, could that be anything to do with why it's not working at all?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: EDIT: I have been having a play about with this, basically, I feel it has something to do with the actual values. I hard coded a line draw from two points I coded myself with positive values 100 and 200, and it drew the line as expected. Would having a negative value, or the fact that the geopoints are long numbers like 344555 have anything to do with the problem? Do I need to put a decimal place into the positive numbers? And is there some way to convert these numbers to screen pixels, or does it do this automatically?

Comment: Finally, if it doesnt, is there anyway to effectively set the canvas scale, so it can accomodate for these minus numbers?

Thanks